# Change in eigenvalues when rank-1 matrix is added to positive definite matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a column vector and $A, B$ are positive definite matrices with eigenvalues $\lambda_A^1 \geq \dots \geq \lambda_A^n$ and $ \lambda_B^1 \geq \dots \geq \lambda_B^n$ respectively. We also know that 
 a) $ \lambda_A^1 \leq \lambda_B^1 $ and $ \lambda_A^n \geq \lambda_B^n $, 
 b) $\operatorname{Trace} (A) = \operatorname{Trace} (B)$ 
 c)  $ \det(A) \leq \det(B) $

What can we say about eigenvalues (or change in eigenvalues) of following matrices (apart from Cauchy interlacing theorem):

1. $ \hat{A} = A + vv^T$
2. $ \hat{B} = B + vv^T$

Is there any relationship between $ \frac{\det(\hat{A})}{\det(A)} $ and $  \frac{\det(\hat{B})}{\det(B)}  $?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, we can say things. The two ingredients you need are the following:

- the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma): $\det(M+xy^T) = (1+y^TM^{-1}x)\det(M)$;
- the [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) identity: $(M+xy^T)^{-1}= M^{-1} - \frac{M^{-1}xy^TM^{-1}}{1+y^TM^{-1}x}$.

Equipped with these things, you can find out more quantitative relationships between the old and new matrices.

**Edit:** The question has been updated to ask about relationships between the ratios of the determinants, which according to the matrix determinant lemma are the quantities 
$$1+v^TA^{-1}v\quad \text{and}\quad 1+v^TB^{-1}v$$
The short general answer is **no**. Even though we have some relationships between the spectra of $A$ and $B$, we can't in general say much about $v^TA^{-1}v$ compared to $v^TB^{-1}v$, since it may happen that $v$ is well-aligned with an eigenvector of $A^{-1}$ of large eigenvalue, and an eigenvector of $B^{-1}$ of small eigenvalue.

An extreme example meeting all conditions in the question would be to take a positive definite matrix $A$ which has large variation in its spectrum, and make $B$ be a rotated copy of $A$, i.e. obtained by conjugating with an orthogonal transformation. Then it may well happen that for some $v$ the ratio of determinants is huge, while for others it's tiny.

Comment: I wasn't clear. Updated the question!

 Is there any relationship between $ \frac{\det(\hat{A})}{\det(A)} $ and $  \frac{\det(\hat{B})}{\det(B)}  $?